# Why does the 2ndbootloader binary file of an Android image is increasing in size by 6724 bytes on incremental builds of the source code?

Tags: boot-loader

I have built the source code of Android five times and on every build of the source code, I am getting image file size increasing at constant rate. 2ndbootloader binary file is increasing as well as boot.img is increasing in size. what might be the possible reasons behind this?

Comment: That doesn't sound good.  It sounds like artefacts from the previous build are getting packed into later builds.  This question may be better asked on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what are the artefacts getting added? what is your approach?